# Can't reconnect to Datalab vm through cloud shell

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I created and successfully used a datalab instance. Afterwards, I stopped the instance.

Now, I'm trying to reconnect to the same datalab instance (using 'datalab connect {instance_name}') but this is resulting in the cloud shell hanging on the "Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/" line forever.

I have successfully ssh'ed into the instance with both the "Connect - SSH" button in the console as well as the cloud shell command "gcloud compute ssh --zone=australia-southeast1-a datalab@{instance_name}". So the vm appears to be working as normal.

What is the issue here preventing the datalab command from executing properly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that firewall rules in your Cloud Project are preventing the connection, or that the Datalab firewall rules and network have been deleted.

Try recreating the datalab instance, which will recreate the firewall rules to see if this helps:
(From https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/lifecycle#updating_the_cloud_datalab_vm_without_deleting_the_notebooks_disk)
datalab delete --keep-disk instance-name
datalab create instance-name

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

When I execute the 'datalab delete --keep-disk ..' and then the 'datalab create ..' commands, I get a prompt; "The network `datalab-network` has firewall rules that were not created by the `datalab` command line tool. Instances created in that network may be open to traffic that they should not be exposed to." I select Y to continue, and it results again in the endless waiting for datalab to be reachable. Is there some way to keep the disk but reset the firewall rules, or alter the rules some other way?

Comment: I then stopped the vm, checked the 'Allow HTTP traffic' and 'Allow HTTPS traffic' in the firewall options of VM instance details, and restarted it with the 'datalab connect ..' command. the result was "Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Connection broken
Attempting to reconnect..."
 And then it again is hanging endlessly on waiting for datalab to be reachable.

Comment: Note; the project's firewall rules regarding datalab-network are to allow tcp ports 22, 443 and 80 for ingress and no rules for egress.